# Add trailing slash htacess multiples redirects

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I added the following rules below in .htacess in a wordpress site to force a redirect with the insertion of / at the end of the url.

```
RewriteEngine on
#Add Trailing slash for end of the URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

**Full .htacess**

```
RewriteEngine on
#Add Trailing slash for end of the URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header set Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://testeidinheiro.com.br.cdn.ampproject.org"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin "https://testeidinheiro.com.br"
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
Header set AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin "https://testeidinheiro.com.br"
</IfModule>

#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://cdn.ampproject.org
#Header set AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin https://testeidinheiro.com.br
#Header set AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin http://testeidinheiro.com.br

#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
#Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WebP Express
# As diretrizes (linhas) entre `BEGIN WebP Express` e` END WebP Express` são
# geradas dinamicamente e só devem ser modificadas através de filtros do WordPress.
# Quaisquer alterações nas diretivas entre esses marcadores serão sobrescritas.
# Plugin is deactivated
# END WebP Express

# AMPFORWPLBROWSERCSTART Browser Caching
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/webp "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/xhtml-xml "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 3 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 3 month"
</IfModule>
# END Caching AMPFORWPLBROWSERCEND


# BEGIN WP Cloudflare Super Page Cache
# As diretrizes (linhas) entre "BEGIN WP Cloudflare Super Page Cache" e "END WP Cloudflare Super Page Cache" são
# geradas dinamicamente e só devem ser modificadas através de filtros do WordPress.
# Quaisquer alterações nas diretivas entre esses marcadores serão sobrescritas.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/xsl "access plus 0 seconds"
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|xsl)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "robots\.txt">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|pdf)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, immutable, max-age=2592000, stale-while-revalidate=86400, stale-if-error=604800"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|eot|swf|svg|webp|avif|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|ogg|mp4|mpeg|avi|mkv|webm|mp3)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, immutable, max-age=31536000, stale-while-revalidate=86400, stale-if-error=604800"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/wp-content/wp-cloudflare-super-page-cache/www.testeidinheiro.com.br/debug.log(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "wp-cron.php">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WP Cloudflare Super Page Cache
#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://cdn.ampproject.org
#Header set AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin https://testeidinheiro.com.br
#Header set AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin http://testeidinheiro.com.br
```

For example: `https://www.testeidinheiro.com/name-post` to `https://www.testeidinheiro.com/name-post/`

[image]

However, as you can see in the screenshot below, the string is not cool.

Why does https send to http and then back to https again?

Comment: Can you share your full htaccess file in the question?

Comment: Where are the rules that redirect your `https` URLs to `http`? Are you using any redirection plugin?

Comment: @AmitVerma, There is no rule about https to http. I don't use any plugin. 
This redirect from https to http and then back to https again occurred after I activated this slash rule

Comment: Check your permalink settings. You can enable the trailing slash from there instead of using a rule to force it.